# Every time I use integrated security, either TRUE or SSPI is uses the logged in computer account

Tags: sql, powershell, automation, active-directory

The following function works great.... but not really.  If I run powershell as another user it uses that ...  I run azure automation and when it passes in a job I get the following:

```
Login failed for user 'corp\server01$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.1]
```

I use the following function:

```
Function SQL-Query {
    param(
        $server,
        $database,
        $username,
        $password,
        $sqlquery
    )
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $server; Database = $database; TrustServerCertificate = True; User ID = $Username; Password = $Password; integrated security = sspi;"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlquery
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    return $DataSet.Tables[0]
}
```

ok well you will say set 'integrated security = false'  yep did that then I get this:

```
Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.1]
```

ok then you will say make sure mixed mode is enabled ... I get this

```
exec master.sys.xp_loginconfig 'login mode'
login mode  Mixed
```

Then you might say well use authentication = active directory password:

```
Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.1]
```

Nothing works.  All I want to do is use a active directory username and password against this database using powershell.

Yeah I know I can use set the hybrid worker to run as another account ... but lets say I am not using azure automation, how the heck can I pass in AD creds without being signed on that account.  Seems to me this is a pretty common thing.

Comment: `integrated security = true` is correct. Looks like Azure Automation is using the Local System account, which is not authorized. `server01$` is the computer system account.

Comment: this is right, but who runs a script should never matter if im passing in the creds to the script.  Someone had to think about this for connection strings for ad accounts before me.

Comment: Integrated Security ignores usernames or passwords. It always executes as the logged in user credentials for that application. For a local desktop app you can `Impersonate`, not sure about Azure

Comment: If you're using Powershell `Connect-AzAccount` there is a parameter `-Credential`

Comment: What I really want to do is just use a active directory username / password but if I take out integrated I always get the:"Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.1] "  even if I add authentication = active directory password.

Comment: I also 100% tried to take out integrated security.  But it always fails back to SQL auth.  And I know that I dont need username / password with integrated security.

Comment: Username and password without integrated security = SQL Auth. With Integrated security = Windows Auth and always ignores the password given. It uses AD credentials from the app. You need to tell the job which AD user to authenticate as. Similar to in Windows Scheduled tasks where you can select a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently running under the Local System account (computer account) of the server, as indicated by the $ sign at the end of `corp\server01$`. This has not been authorized to connect to your SQL Server instance.

When the connection string contains `Integrated security=true` (Windows Authentication), the `username` and `password` fields are ignored, as they only relate to SQL Authentication. Windows Authentication uses the cached Windows credential for the client app, in this case the Azure Automation job.

You need to setup a [RunAs account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account) so that the Azure Automation job has an account to use.
You could, if you want, just add the computer account to the Windows Authentication user group in MSSQL, but that doesn't sound so ideal.

Comment: I find it really odd that I cant just leave out integrated security and pass in a UPN and password and have that work.  So I guess the final solution would be what you said to do or to write up some PowerShell that does impersonation.

Comment: @WilliamLee You misunderstand how Windows Auth works. If using SQL Auth, the username and password is verified against a login that has that username and password, but when Windows Auth is used, the client driver passes the Kerberos/NTLM ticket of the Windows login already in use. So if you are logged in as someone else, you may not be authorized e.g. there is no login valid for that computer SYSTEM account, then you must impersonate.

Comment: @WilliamLee Note also that the server running MSSQL must be able to authenticate that Kerberos ticket via a domain controller in AD, or NTLM via hashing

Comment: That does make sense, but only that SQL is so old no one ever updated it.  I would still figure that SQL would get the creds and then do the magic on its end when its passed some flag like windowsauth = true and the upn / pwd.

Comment: No, it's very clever. It means the client has a pre-authenticated Kerberos ticket used in Single Sign On, that it can pass straight to the server. Otherwise you need to start saving passwords in plain text somewhere, or keep asking the user to enter it. Fundamentally, Windows Auth tells the server "This is who I am" not "This is what the password is". Google OAuth2, as well as most SSO, work on a similar principle.

Comment: To me its just a management issue.  Id rather manage all my usernames and passwords in AD and store passwords in a HSM somewhere accessing them programmatically and only deal with logging and monitoring from a single system.  How it works now we would have to manage SQL creds with yet another place for someone to mess up and not apply the password policy.   Anywho long way for me to say I added the machine account to the SQL server and called it a day.

Comment: With WIndows Auth there is only one username/password to manage: the AD one. With SQL Auth you have another set. Using Machine account: not major, just check SQL permissions are ok, and who has Admin rights on that machine (anyone with Admin can elevate to SYSTEM).